# Running sql file using rails migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, db2, migration

I am facing issue while running a sql file containing multiple sql queries that creates table in a db .
The db is DB2 ,I created a migration file ,in which it read a sql file and executes the sql queries in that file ,the issue is it executes only one query and creates only one table in that sql file ie which is the first query.

Any idea how to overcome this issue

The code sniplet is below:

```
enter code here
class CreateTablesForPoject < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    begin
      user = RailsUser.first
    rescue => e 
     fixed_patches = %w(CREATETABLES.sql)

     sql = File.read("db/ddl/#{fixed_patches.first}")

     statements = sql.split(/;$/)

     statements.each do |statement|
       execute(statement)
     end
    end
  end
end
```

Note: The file reading and the splitting of query is all fine.. it doesn't have any issues The migration runs and executes all the query, but fails when the alter table query or any query which is base on pervious table creation fails. The issue which I feel is that after running one query the db connection goes off and so the table doesn't get created so the query base on pervious table creation fails.

Comment: What debugging have you tried? e.g. what is the outcome of the assignment to statements? Is that split statement returning what you expect it to? ditto for the File.read statement.

Comment: @margo: The file reading and the splitting of query is all fine.. it don't have any issues
The migration runs and executes all the query, but fails when the alter table query or any query which is base on pervious table creation fails.
The issue which I feel is that after running one query the db connection goes off and so the table doesn't get created so the query base on pervious table creation fails

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
class CreateTablesForPoject < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    begin
      user = RailsUser.first
    rescue => e 
     fixed_patches = %w(CREATETABLES.sql)

     sql = File.read("db/ddl/#{fixed_patches.first}")
     statements = sql.split(/;/)
     statements.pop # remote empty line
     ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      statements.each do |statement|
        connection.execute(statement)
      end
    end
  end
end
```